# How to rotate my text

Tags: rotating

I need to rotate by 180° the text. Just to read normally!!!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid]

\psarc(4,4){2}{0}{180}
\psset{linestyle=none,xunit=1cm,yunit=1.05cm}
\pstextpath[c]{%
\psarc(4,4){2}{0}{180}}{%
\color{red} 25\% OFP distance}

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\psarcn` instead of `\psarc` helps:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid]

\psarc(4,4){2}{0}{180}
\psset{linestyle=none,xunit=1cm,yunit=1.05cm}
\pstextpath[c]{%
  \psarcn(4,4){2}{180}{0}%
}{%
 \color{red}25\% OFP distance%
}

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]